# If A U B and A ∩ B are recognizable, then is one of A, A', B, B' also recognizable?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, sets, turing-recognizable

I know that if decidability of $A \cap B$ and $A \cup B$ doesn’t
guarantee the decidability of any of $A$ or $B$. We can prove that:

ATM is not decidable. Since decidable languages are closed under complementation, ATM' is also not decidable. But $\textrm{ATM} \cup \textrm{ATM}' = \Sigma^*$ and $\textrm{ATM} \cap \textrm{ATM}' = \varnothing$ both are decidable.

But what about recognizability?

Answer (score 1):

Then answer is no.

The language $A$ of Turing machines that halt on every input is not recognizable, but its complement $A^c$ is also not recognizable.
Then both $A \cup A^c = \Sigma^*$ and $A \cap A^c = \varnothing$ are recognizable, but neither are $A$ nor $A^c$.